# How to pass string data from jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

<% String successmessage=(String)request.getAttribute("sm");%>

I have alert.js file in my eclipse how can I transfer successmessage variable from JSP to javascript for alert message

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a hidden span and query for it. e.g:

```
<span hidden id="successMessage">
  <%= request.getAttribute("sm")%>
</span>
```

and make sure you got your HTML escaping figured out!

Then in javascript:

```
const msg = document.getElementById("successMessage").textContent;
```

There are many others, but given that you're using JSP, it sounds like the dated stuff is what you're looking for.

Comment: Got it, it's helped me